# Running nosetests from a shell script fails - 'No such file ...'

Tags: python, shell, sh, nose

I can run the following in my project root in the terminal just fine ...

`$ nosetests tests/autogen/output/ifort/9-1_linux_intel`

However placing the same in `runtests.sh` and running using `sh runtests.sh` I get the following ...

```
(base) brendan@MacBook-Pro py-fortranformat % sh runtests.sh
E
======================================================================
)RROR: Failure: OSError (No such file /Users/brendan/Developer/py-fortranformat/tests/autogen/output/ifort/9-1_linux_intel
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brendan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 42, in runTest
    raise self.exc_class(self.exc_val)
OSError: No such file /Users/brendan/Developer/py-fortranformat/tests/autogen/output/ifort/9-1_linux_intel

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I've tried different shell commands e.g. `zsh runtests.sh` but still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The file is DOS formatted. Make sure it's unix formatted. Your editor should be able to help with this.

Comment: The reason I surmised this is because of the `)R` at the _start_ of the error line, which indicates a carriage-return character at the end of the line, as the `)` belongs to the error message.